# Enlarging a compact set in order to improve its shape

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

In my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359390/is-it-possible-to-connect-every-compact-set) it was established that if $X$ is a metrizable, connected, locally path connected space and $K\subset X$ is compact, then there is a Peano continuum $L\subset X$ such that $K\subset L$. This motivated the following questions.

> Let $X$ be as above and $\pi_k(X)$ is trivial, for $k=0,...,n$ (resp $X$ is contractible). If $K\subset X$ is a Peano continuum, can we find a compact $L\subset X$ such that $K\subset L$ and $\pi_k(L)$ is trivial, for $k=0,...,n$ (resp $L$ is contractible)?

Regarding the "contractible version", here is an idea that does not work: let $F:X\times[0,1] \to X$ be a homotopy from the identity to a constant. It is tempting to try to show that $F(K\times [0,1])$ is the set that we are looking for. However, if we started with $K$ a singleton, the obtained set can be any Peano continuum, and so not necessarily contractible.

**Edit:** There is a good candidate for a counterexample suggested by HJRW. Let $X$ be the [Whitehead manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold), which is a contractible $3$-dimensional manifold, not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is proven in the paper *Brick & Mihalik - The QSF property for groups and spaces*, that $X$ fails the so called QSF property. This amounts to existence of subcomplex $A$ of $X$ such that there is no celluar map $f:K\to X$ of a finite simply connected complex such that $f|_{f^{-1}(A)}\to A$ is a homeomorphism. In particular, there is no finite simply connected subcomplex $L\supset A$.

Hence, we are almost done: there is a compact set (in a contractible manifold) that cannot be included into a simply-connected **subcomplex**. The missing ingredient therefore is:

> Can every simply connected $M\subset X$ be included in a simply connected finite subcomplex of $X$?

Interestingly, in Definition 1.5 [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1576.pdf), the QSF property is defined with no reference to complexes, and in fact is exactly what i need. However, that's the only place i saw this definition, so it's not 100% clear it is equivalent to the more common one.

Comment: Maybe the technique of "engulfing" is helpful, e.g. Chapter 3 of Daverman-Venema, Embeddings in manifolds.

Comment: Regarding the contractible version, you might like to think a bit about the Whitehead manifold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_manifold .  It's a contractible 3-manifold, but I believe that it cannot be filtered by compact, simply connected subsets.

Comment: @HJRW what does "filtered by compact, simply connected subsets" mean? sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: I’d call a manifold $M$ “filtered by compact, simply connected subsets” if it can be written as an ascending union $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} K_n$, where each $K_n$ is compact and simply connected.

Comment: @HJRW that would completely answer my question (even more). Do you know a reference for that claim?

Comment: You could start with: Brick & Mihalik, The QSF property for groups and spaces, *Math. Z.* (1995) . The QSF property is a bit more complicated than the definition I gave above, but I think it's in the same spirit.

Comment: @HJRW please tell me if i understand correctly. It says after Theorem 1.1 that the Whitehead manifold $X$ does not have QSF. Since it is simply connected, it is its own uiversal cover. Thus, there is a finite subcomplex $A$ of $X$ such that there is no celluar map of a finite simply connected complex $K$ which homeomorphically "covers" $A$. In particular, there is no finite simply connected $L\supset A$. The missing ingredient however is: can every simply connected $M\subset X$ be included in a simply connected complex?

Comment: Interestingly, in Definition 1.5 by the link below, everything is stated in "general-topological language", with no mentioning of complexes. However, that's the only place i saw this definition, so it's not 100% clear they are equivalent. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.1576.pdf

Comment: @erz: I think pointing you in the direction of this literature is pretty much the limit of my expertise!  You could also check out Whitehead's original paper. My one other suggestion is to look at Part V of Ross Geoghegan's book *Topological methods in group theory*, which I think covers some of these kind of notions.

Comment: @HJRW thank you for your help in any case! Your suggestion of QSF was very helpful! I'll check the book.